# Актёр должен убедительно существовать, то, что зритель называет «играть», - как быть с "то"?

Tags: пунктуация

> Актёр должен убедительно существовать, то, что зритель называет
>   «играть», и ведь продолжать играть, и играть одно и то же на
>   протяжении многих лет, и в любом настроении – это такая работа.

Спасут ли ситуацию тире? А может, и так всё хорошо?...

Актёр должен убедительно существовать – то, что зритель называет «играть», – и ведь продолжать играть, и играть одно и то же на

> протяжении многих лет, и в любом настроении – это такая работа.

Да-с, второе тире явно портит всю красоту; скобки?

А! вторая скобка, закрывающая так же отрывает от «играть»!...

Может, предложите мне что-нибудь с "то"?..

СПАСИБО!

Оу! А если так:

*Актёр должен убедительно существовать – то, что зритель называет «играть», и ведь продолжать играть, и играть одно и то же на протяжении многих лет, и в любом настроении: это такая работа.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мои варианты:

**Актёр должен убедительно существовать (то, что зритель называет «играть») — и ведь продолжать играть, и играть одно и то же на протяжении многих лет, и в любом настроении. Это такая работа.**

**Актёр должен убедительно существовать — то, что зритель называет «играть», — и ведь продолжать играть, и играть одно и то же на протяжении многих лет, и в любом настроении. Это такая работа.**

"Это такая работа" — вывод настолько важный, что не должен теряться в многословном предложении.

Answer (score 1):

**Еще вариант** (лишние слова убрали, длинные слова сделали короче):

Актёр должен убедительно существовать (то, что зритель называет «играть»), причем играть одно и тО же,  много лет и в любом настроЕнии – это такая работа.

Answer (score 0):

А так не подойдет?
Актер должен убедительно существовать на сцене - зритель называет это "играть" - играть одно и то же на протяжении многих лет и в любом настроении: работа такая.

Answer (score 0):

Актёр должен убедительно существовать — это [именно] то, что зритель называет «играть»; и ведь продолжать играть, и играть одно и то же на протяжении многих лет, и в любом настроении. Это — такая работа.

Или:
Актёр должен убедительно существовать — это [именно] то, что зритель называет «играть» (и ведь продолжать играть, и играть одно и то же на протяжении многих лет, и в любом настроении!). Это такая работа.

Или:
Актёр должен убедительно существовать — это [именно] то, что зритель называет «играть» (и ведь продолжать играть, и играть одно и то же на протяжении многих лет, и в любом настроении!), это такая работа.